# PHP GetPayload method is not returning the body of the message

Tags: php, email, gmail-api

I'm using the PHP GMAIL API in order to import emails into a custom ticketing system.  During my testing, I was able to successfully import all emails put one.  The email in question has a signature at the bottom.

"_____________________________________________________

Test client address

123 address"

When I view the email through a web browser, Gmail throws a "trimmed content" message on the message even though it's the first email in the thread.  This problem only happens in this one instance.

```
$message = $gmailService->users_messages->get($ticketToken->emailAccount,$messageHeader->getId() );
$messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
$headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
$parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();

$body = $parts[0]['body'];
$rawData = $body->data;

$sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
$decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please explain on the what do you mean by trimmed content? Is GMAIL API not showing the entire message?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    $body = $message->getPayload()->getBody();

    $rawData = $body->data;

    $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');

    $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
```